# Restrict(sandbox) node.js file access

Tags: node.js, security

I am developing a web app, and for security reasons I want node to only be able to access a specific folder(and sub-folders).
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Node needs to be able to read your code, obviously, but it you are talking about write access, then yes, you can do that using standard OS permissions by restricting the user the node app is running as to read-only. ie have those files the node app shouldn't be able to right to owned by another user.

Comment: no what i was looking for. i have the app in a folder and i want it it only be able to access that one. the code is stored in there to. i dont want anyone to be able to look at anything outside this "sandbox"

Comment: @Kriso have you figured it out by any chance eventually?